# Login loop in fresh installation of Nextcloud 18

Tags: nextcloud

After a fresh installation of Nextcloud 18, I was able to access to the site without any problem, but when I tried to login for the very first start with my *admin* user, I went into a login loop, without any message of error.

I cleaned the `/data/nextcloud.log` file, and I tried to login again, then, I got this on the log:

```
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-EAAAAI","level":3,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"POST","url":"/index.php/login","message":"is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my-site-folder/public_html:/tmp:/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite:/opt/php7-3/lib/php:/opt/ferozo/etc/suspen:/opt/ferozo/suspended.page) at /home/my-site-folder/public_html/nc/lib/private/TempManager.php#260","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-EAAAAI","level":2,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"/index.php/login","message":"Temporary directory /home/my-site-folder/tmpsite is not present or writable","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-IAAAAI","level":3,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/files/","message":"is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my-site-folder/public_html:/tmp:/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite:/opt/php7-3/lib/php:/opt/ferozo/etc/suspen:/opt/ferozo/suspended.page) at /home/my-site-folder/public_html/nc/lib/private/TempManager.php#260","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-IAAAAI","level":2,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/apps/files/","message":"Temporary directory /home/my-site-folder/tmpsite is not present or writable","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-MAAAAI","level":3,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/login?redirect_url=/index.php/apps/files/","message":"is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my-site-folder/public_html:/tmp:/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite:/opt/php7-3/lib/php:/opt/ferozo/etc/suspen:/opt/ferozo/suspended.page) at /home/my-site-folder/public_html/nc/lib/private/TempManager.php#260","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-MAAAAI","level":2,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"GET","url":"/index.php/login?redirect_url=/index.php/apps/files/","message":"Temporary directory /home/my-site-folder/tmpsite is not present or writable","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-QAAAAI","level":3,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/cron.php","message":"is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/my-site-folder/public_html:/tmp:/home/my-site-folder/tmpsite:/opt/php7-3/lib/php:/opt/ferozo/etc/suspen:/opt/ferozo/suspended.page) at /home/my-site-folder/public_html/nc/lib/private/TempManager.php#260","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
{"reqId":"Xp8LkrMrcw4AABOVg-QAAAAI","level":2,"time":"2020-04-21T15:04:50+00:00","remoteAddr":"my-IP","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"GET","url":"/cron.php","message":"Temporary directory /home/my-site-folder/tmpsite is not present or writable","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36","version":"18.0.3.0"}
```

I couldn't find a solution on the Nextcloud community.

Additional information: I'm running PHP 7.3 on Apache 2.4, over Centos 6.

Answer (score 0):

I paid attention to the first line of the error log:

```
"message":"Temporary directory /home/my-site-folder/tmpsite is not present or writable"
```

Then, I created the `tmpsite` exactly where Nextcloud was looking for it (in my case, inside `/home/my-site-folder`), and I gave the folder, read-write-execute permissions.

Problem solved.